# Camel - StringTemplate doesn't display CamelBatchSize

Tags: apache-camel

I've a small string template (fragment for testing):

```
{headers.CamelBatchSize}
{headers.CamelFileName}
{headers.CamelFilePath}
{headers.fileCount}
```

And when I call it:

```
        <setHeader headerName="fileCount">
            <simple>${headers.CamelBatchSize}</simple>
        </setHeader>
        <to uri="string-template:file:notifymail.tm?delimiterStart={&amp;delimiterStop=}" />
```

The first row is empty (CamelBatchSize) while the others displayed well. Why cannot I use the CamelBatchSize (without putting it into another header variable)? Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a Batch-Consumer? https://camel.apache.org/batch-consumer.html

Comment: Yes, of course (sftp). I'm sorry, I forgot to mention it. The fileCount got the good value in the setHeader. Thanks.